# Duhamel formula for propagators

Tags: classical-mechanics, mathematical-physics, oscillators, vibrations

Let $\dot{z} = A(t)z + b(t)$ with $ z(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A(t)$ be a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. A propagator is also a linear map $P(t,s):$ $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n:$ $z(s) \rightarrow z(t)$ and has the following properties:

1. $P(t,r)P(r,s) = P(t,s)$
2. $P(s,s) = id$
3. $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}P(t,s) = A(t)P(t,s)$

The Duhamel formula is the following (a general solution to: $z(t) = P(t,s)z(s) + \int_s^t d\tau P(t,\tau)b(\tau)$

I'm trying to prove it by simply deriving it:

$\dot{z} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}P(t,s)z(s) + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_s^t d\tau P(t,\tau)b(\tau) = A(t)P(t,s)z(s) + P(t,t)b(t) + \int_s^t A(t)P(t,\tau)b(\tau) = A(t)z(t) +b(t) + \int_s^t A(t)P(t,\tau)b(\tau)$

This is nearly the form that I want (I used equation 2 and 3 and standard properties of the integral and dervative, for those wondering), but I can't see right now how the intgeral equals to zero.

Anyone can tell me?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\dot{z}(t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}P(t,s)z(s) + \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_s^t d\tau P(t,\tau)b(\tau)$

$= A(t)P(t,s)z(s) + P(t,t)b(t) + \int_s^t A(t)P(t,\tau)b(\tau)$

$= A(t) P(t,s)z(s)  +b(t) + A(t) \int_s^t P(t,\tau)b(\tau)$

$= A(t) [ P(t,s)z(s)  + \int_s^t P(t,\tau)b(\tau)]  + b(t)  $

$= A(t)  z(t)  + b(t)  $

Comment: This is kinda self referencing. This doesn't really prove the equation, does it?

Comment: I don't understand your "self-referencing". Beginning with the hypothesis that a general solution is $z(t) = P(t,s)z(s) + \int_s^t d\tau P(t,\tau)b(\tau)$, then we demonstrate that : $\dot{z}(t) = A(t)  z(t)  + b(t)$